# ¿Cómo puedo importar un documento csv de excel?

Tags: r, rstudio, ciencia-de-datos

Intenté hacerlo con el paquete `xlsx` pero me tira este error al cargar el paquete:

> library(xlsx)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Answer (score 1):

Este problema del paquete `xlsx` se debe seguramente, a que no tienes instalado JAVA en tu equipo, o que R no puede ubicar el mismo (por ejemplo versiones incompatibles 32 / 64 bits). La instalación de JAVA puedes eventualmente descargarla desde [aquí](https://www.java.com/en/download/) . Revisa que la arquitectura de R y JAVA sean consistentes (ambas de 32 o de 64 bits).

De cualquier manera, mencionas que lo que buscas es importar un archivo de tipo `csv` para la cual no necesitas para nada `xlsx`, con la funcionalidad básica de R puedes lograrlo. Puedes usar [`read.csv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html), por ejemplo con una configuración muy básica:

```
read.csv(file = "path al archivo csv", 
         header = TRUE,                # Archivo con encabezados de columna
         sep = ","                     # Caracter separador de columnas
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instala el paquete `readr`, que sirve para leer archivos de Excel, sin necesidad de usar Java (que genera problemas siempre). Este paquete es más rápido y optimizado que la funcion `read.csv` de la libreria base.

```
#Instalacion del paquete
install.packages("readr")
library(readr)
```

Uso de la libreria:

```
#Leer el archivo csv
datos <- read_csv(file = "Ruta_Del_Archivo.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a lo indicado por Patricio, puedes definir la ubicación de JAVA antes de cargar la librería `xlsx`. A mi me pasaba algo similar en el PC del trabajo, que es de 64 bits, pero tiene una versión de JAVA de 32 bits. La ubicación mía de JAVA actual es "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221", pero como nos actualizan constantemente los equipos (por ende, las versiones), preferí dejarlo como el código siguiente:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = list.files("C:/Program Files/Java", pattern ="jre", full.names = T))
# Y luego cargar la librería xlsx
library(xlsx)
```

Ahora, si es por leer un archivo *.cvs, me parece que es más óptimo utilizar la función `fread` de la librería `data.table` [ir a documentación](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.8.8/topics/fread).

Saludos!